# Is there a way in TestCafe to validate Chrome network calls?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a test case where I need to navigate to a webPage and validate the network calls in chrome browser for that page. Ideally, I would take them in a variable and filter them for certain analytics related calls and validate their values.

This can be done through chrome capabilities in Selenium. See doc here: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging/performance-log   but I am trying to do this through testCafe?

I came across this documentation: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/    on testCafe site but I am not sure if this is same as getting hold of performance logs in chrome. Basically, if I am able to grab hold of all the calls in the network tab under developer tools in chrome, I should be able to filter it using JavaScript and complete my testing.

Any inputs related to this would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is the same: the `RequestLogger` object [stores all HTTP requests sent and responses received while the test is running](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html). It's the same as grabbing hold of your network activity (the "Network" tab) during the **current** test run. You can also tune your `Logger` using both `filter` and `options` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, appreciate it. I will try to integrate it in my tests

Comment: @V.Airrich   I tried what you had suggested - requestLogger but I am not clear as to how I can accomplish this. Here is my attempt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55700475/using-testcafe-requestlogger-to-retrieve-chrome-performance-logs-fails

Comment: Some Qs that come to mind. Do I start tracking before the tab click for which I need to collect logs or do I start tracking after the tab click. Once I start tracking how I get request URL , the documentation doesn't make this clear - an example would be helpful and much appreciated !