# Using testCafe 'requestLogger' to retrieve chrome performance logs fails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

This is in continuation of this thread: [Is there a way in TestCafe to validate Chrome network calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642888/is-there-a-way-in-testcafe-to-validate-chrome-network-calls)

Here is my testCafe attempt to retrieve all the network logs(i.e. network tab in developer tools) from chrome. I am having issues getting anything printed on console.

```
const logger = RequestLogger('https://studenthome.com',{        
    logRequestHeaders: true,   
    logRequestBody: true,
    logResponseHeaders: true,
    logResponseBody:    true
});
    test  
    ('My  test - Demo', async t => {
        await t.navigateTo('https://appURL.com/app/home/students');//navigate to app launch
        await page_students.click_studentNameLink();//click on student name
        await t
            .expect(await page_students.exists_ListPageHeader()).ok('do something async', { allowUnawaitedPromise: true })       //validate list header
       await t
       .addRequestHooks(logger)     //start tracking requests
       let url = await page_studentList.click_tab();//click on the tab for which requests need to be validated

       let c = await logger.count; //check count of request. Should be 66

       await console.log(c);
        await console.log(logger.requests[2]);    // get the url for 2nd request
    }); 

I see this in console:

    [Function: count]
    undefined
```

Here is picture from google as an illustration of what I am trying to achieve.  I navigate to google.com and opened up developer tools> network tab. Then I clicked on store link and captured logs. The request URLs I am trying to collect are highlighted. I can get all the urls and then filter to the one I require.

[image]

The following, I have already tried

```
await console.log(logger.requests); // undefined
await console.log(logger.requests[*]); // undefined
await console.log(logger.requests[0].response.headers); //undefined
await logger.count();//count not a function
```

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using different urls in your test page ('https://appURL.com/app/home/students') and your logger ('https://studenthome.com'). This is probably the cause.
Your Request Logger records only requests to 'https://studenthome.com'.

In your screenshot I see the url 'http://store.google.com', which differs from the logger url, so the logger does not process it.

You can pass a RegExp as a first arg of the [RequestLogger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestlogger/) constructor to all requests which match your RegExp.

I have created a sample:

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const logger = RequestLogger(/google/, {
    logRequestHeaders:  true,
    logRequestBody:     true,
    logResponseHeaders: true,
    logResponseBody:    true
});

fixture `test`
    .page('http://google.com');

    test('test', async t => {
        await t.addRequestHooks(logger);

        await t.typeText('input[name="q"]', 'test');
        await t.typeText('input[name="q"]', '1');
        await t.typeText('input[name="q"]', '2');
        await t.pressKey('enter');

        const logRecord = logger.requests.length;

        console.log(logger.requests.map(r => r.request.url));
    });
```

Comment: When I perform this step "let url = await page_studentList.click_tab()" the resulting page has this URL "https://studenthome.com". I guess I am not clear when I should start tracking requests. I would like to track requests for the page that appears after click_tab() function.

Comment: Also, the illustration using google was just for illustration(an image representation) as to what I am trying to achieve out of this. I can't really disclose any app info as it is confidential and therefore had to make stuff up including the google example.Hope, I am making sense.

Comment: I tried something similar to what you have:                                                                await t.addRequestHooks(logger);                                                                          
 let url = await page_studentList.click_tab();                
 const c = await logger.requests.length;
 await console.log(c);
 await console.log(logger.requests.map(r => r.request.url));   This is what that get printed in console:  [ 'https://studenthome.com' ]

Comment: This means that RequestLogger works. You clicked a tab. Browser requested 'studenthome.com' and logger saved this information. It's the correct behavior

Comment: The scenario I am trying to test is - when the user clicks on the tab, we pick all the network logs from it. There 72 requests made when I look at the network tab in chrome developer tools. Some of the requests out of the 72 are for analytics collection. And I'd like to filter those requests and validate the request URLs for those. RequestLogger is returning back the webpage url and I need the network calls that happen when I travel to a webpage.

Comment: I understand. I prepared another sample. Please have a look at 
https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/c2b1bbf62e1190c766fd61715c6a1f40
 
I set logger to log all requests. After setting the logger, test navigates to your url. Then I added timeout, which is required for all images.
As a result, I've got 68 requests. There is a difference between my 68 and your 72 requests, but I think it can be related to the specifics of your test.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to answer my post on github. I modified the code a bit and was able to filter the analytics calls alone from the list of chrome network calls. Please note console.log(logger.requests.map(r => r.request.url)) did not work for some reason. It kept printing only 15 urls not matter how much timeout I gave, or where I initiated the logger( be it test, fixture or t object). So, made const c to store it first and print it in async manner using await. I still don't get 72 requests. I get 33 but my google analytics calls are getting printed